# Jquery BlockUI to block external links

Tags: javascript, jquery, blockui

I was looking for a nice way when you click an link with domain different than .com to have an alert that blocks the screen(Jquery BlockUI) and blocks the going to the external link, until you press OK to go to the link or Cancel to don't go to the link.
But at the moment the when I click the link it will open the link and then block the Ui.

.

```
<a href="http://www.ibm.it/" target="_blank" onClick="onClick_handler(this)">IBM</a>
```

.

```
function onClick_handler(e) {
    var mySource = window.event.srcElement;
    if ((mySource.tagName == "A")) {
        if (mySource.href.indexOf("com") == -1) 
        {
            blockTheScreen(" ATTENTION YOU ARE EXITING THE .COM WEB SITE"
                + "<button type='button' id='OK' >OK</button>"
                + "<button type='button' id='Cancel' >Cancel</button>"
                );
        }
```

.

```
function blockTheScreen(fnBlockUiText){
    $.blockUI(
        { message: $(fnBlockUiText)
            , css: { 
                backgroundColor: '#ddd', 
                color: '#00f',
                width: '700px', 
                height: '500px', 
                padding: '12px',
                position: 'fixed',
                top: '50%', 
                left: '50%',
                marginTop: '-250px',
                marginLeft: '-350px',
            }
        });
```

Comment: It opens, because you do not cancel the link.

Answer (score 0):

At the end of your `function onClick_handler(e)` do a `return false;` to prevent it to do the *default action of the clicked element*

### Edit

Dont prevent it on the end of function this will disable all of the links, instead put return false in your if statement true block...

```
if (mySource.href.indexOf("com") == -1) 
{
    blockTheScreen(" ATTENTION YOU ARE EXITING THE .COM WEB SITE"
                    + "<button type='button' id='OK' >OK</button>"
                    + "<button type='button' id='Cancel' >Cancel</button>");
    return false;
}
```

Comment: @user2598571 if it didnt work, there must be another problem with your code make sure it hits to return false code. And check that demo: http://jsfiddle.net/6bmpyrh0/4/ and if you can provide a demo with the problem we can help you better.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
<a href="http://www.ibm.it/" target="_blank" onClick="onClick_handler(this)">IBM</a>
```

to
    IBM

Additionally, after the call to `blockTheScreen`, in the innermost `if`, add a

```
return false;
```

at the end of it